# Automatically fill the current date in a cell if the data is not empty in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have 9 columns of data. With the requirement in column 9 that there are data, the first column will dynamically fill in the current date.

I use the formula "= ArrayFormula (IF (ISTEXT (D7), TODAY ()," "))" but the problem is that if it passes the next day it will change to the next day's date. I do not want it to change the day after the new day, what should I do?

Comment: Please upload a sample sheet or provide the desired output you want.

Comment: Here :https://i.imgur.com/ysMjONC.png - I want if i fill data in column I (Green) then column B (Red) auto fill date today but not change date in tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible using a simple google sheet function.

If you want to use a google script to solve this then you can apply below:

```
function onEdit(){

dateStamp();

}

function dateStamp() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data')//change sheet name per your requirement;
  const date = new Date();
  const lr = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  const  dataRange = ss.getRange(2,9,lr-1).getValues() //change range per your requirement;
  const  dateRange = ss.getRange(2,2,lr-1).getValues() //change range per your requirement;
  
  for (i=0; i<dataRange.length; i++){

    if(dataRange[i] !=''){

      if (dateRange[i] == '')

      ss.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(date);

      
    }

  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in Column A
`=arrayformula(ifs(len(i1)=0,"",A1="",Today(),true,""))`